# How to add suport library,ActionBarActivity and themes to android project?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I added android-support-v7-appcompat. Next I clicked on each file in directory \libs. Then I clicked android-support-v7-appcompat and opened properties. Next checked files from directory libs and unchecked Android Dependencies. Next opened properties of myproject. Went to the projects and by Add button added android-support-v7-appcompat.

But nothing is working. How can I make ActionBarActivity(there is no new variants) and how can I add a theme. I used to add in manifest to activity, tried to add it to the style.xml Please help me. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If starting a new project now, I would do the same as you and use Action Bar Compat . This should help : [ActionBarCompat - how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154476/actionbarcompat-how-to-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

Is necessary use and extra library for use the ActionBar, not only the android-support-library. Try to use the ActionBarSherlockLibrary (this library do that you want to do).

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: But what I did wrong?

Comment: I believe that is a few hard know what do you do exactly wrong without seeing your code, or your proyect. But if you are using the ActionBarSherlockLibrary for support the ActionBar in 2.x versions, I recommend look the next tutorial http://androcode.es/2012/03/introduccion-a-actionbarsherlock/ the only thing is that it is in Spanish, if you aren't supporting actionbar for 2.x versions look the next tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/ (are in english). I hope you work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sample locate $ANDROID_SDK/samples/android-18/ui/actionbarcompat/
2. ActionBarCompat library project locate on $ANDROID_SDK/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat

Comment: I agree with you, but it doesn't solve my problem