# How to add ActionBarActivity in Android Project?

Tags: android, project

I'm not able to add ActionBarActivity in my Android project. There are no options of `appcpmpat-v7` in any of my project.

What i do now?

Answer (score 2):

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");

    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
            .findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCl`enter code here`ick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication`enter code here`Context(), "Refresh Clicked!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Also u need to Implement the"Actionbaractivity"

Answer (score 1):

If this is a gradle based project then you can add the following dependency in your build.gradle file which will import this dependency.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

PS: 23.0.0 is the latest version targeting android M. You can use 21 or 22 as well

Answer (score 0):

You should have dependency in your gradle file for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0

And you mistyped name of class in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here [How to add suport library,ActionBarActivity and themes to android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891879/how-to-add-suport-library-actionbaractivity-and-themes-to-android-project)
If your workspace does not contain appcompat, it will be automatically made by Eclipse.