# How to add ActionBarActivity into a Project workspace?

Tags: android

I'm trying to add `ActionbarActivity` in my android project as i want to use `android.support.v7.widgets.Gridlayout`.

I tried to create module appcompat-v7 in project structure
still it shoes `ActionbarActivity` symbol cannot be resolved

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public void image(View view){
        GridLayout grid = findViewBYId(R.id.gridlayout);
        ImageView image =  findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        image.setImageResource(dragon2);
}
```

if i use `AppcompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`
application crashes at
`GridLayout grid = findViewBYId(R.id.gridlayout)`

followed some methods
http://www.androiddocs.com/tools/support-library/features.html
[[How to add ActionBarActivity in Android Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310681/how-to-add-actionbaractivity-in-android-project][2])

Please help.

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2019-07-07 01:51:24.981 9256-9256/com.example.gameconnect3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gameconnect3, PID: 9256
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27301)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
```

Comment: Could you share the error stack trace?

Comment: Added the stack trace.