# how to get the action bar in min sdk version=8?

Tags: android, sdk, android-actionbar

I have done an apk with action bar. it's min sdk version is 11, I want to change it to 8. What are the necessary  supporting files which I should add to make the min sdk version to 8.?

Answer (score 1):

Use AppCompact library (appcompat v7) from the support library

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Download the support library. Import into workspace. Can be found at `sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompact`.

Check the below link for setup

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Reference the library in your android project. Extend `ActionBarActivity`. use `Theme.AppCompact`

Or use `ActionBarSherlock`

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Download the sherlock library. import into workspace. Reference the library and extend `SherlockActivity`

Comment: Theme.AppCompact is not available for me , Which other theme should I use?

Comment: @VV it should be available you check again

Comment: @VV check the second link the is straight from developer blog use that

Answer (score 1):

Use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) is an extension of the support library designed to facilitate the use of the action bar design pattern across all versions of Android with a single API.

The library will automatically use the native action bar when appropriate or will automatically wrap a custom implementation around your layouts. This allows you to easily develop an application with an action bar for every version of Android from 2.x and up

Comment: How we are using the Action Bar Sherlock. Just import the file . What we do more to get it correctly .

Comment: 1- Download Library https://api.github.com/repos/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/zipball/4.4.0
2- Import it as Eclipse project.
3- Add this library to your project.
4- Getting started http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project/
5-There are demo projects inside the library you just downloaded "actionbarsherlock-samples", which will be very helpful especially "demos".

Comment: Hi 
I add The Lib as you told. But unfortunately when I put the Sherlock in to my project all my R file get corrected. If I remove the lib the error will not be there, Why it is happening.?

Answer (score 0):

Use `actionbar-compat` in android support library v7. Check [this,](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) [this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154476/actionbarcompat-how-to-use-it)  [this](http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-how-to-use/), [and this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html). Port actionbar back to 2.1. Hope that helps.

Comment: That means I have to do two steps 1. Import the library and change the theme . Theme.AppCompact is not available for me which one should I use instead of that.

Comment: Have you checked the links I provided yet?